# Inserting values for a classification system attribute via impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have a classification system attribute in a classification class that classifies all categories in my catalog.

This attribute is called Vanprijs. I can add values to this attribute for different products/variants on the hMC. Like on the picture below, but how can I add these values via impex files?

[image]

I did try this, but the importer doesn't recognize Vanprijs as a known attribute:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ModelVariantProduct;$baseProduct;code[unique=true];name[lang=$lang];Vanprijs;$catalogVersion;$approved
;B300047;M300047;Toiletverhoger (met deksel en stabiele armleuningen);10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's done (note the 2 variables **$clAttrModifiers** and **$vanprijsFeature**):

```
$lang=nl
$productCatalog=myProductCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]
$approved=approvalstatus(code)[default='check']
$baseProduct=baseProduct(code,$catalogVersion)
$clAttrModifiers=system='MySystemClassifications',version='General',translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeTranslator,lang=nl
$vanprijsFeature=@Vanprijs[$clAttrModifiers];


INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$vanprijsFeature;$catalogVersion
;M300047;200.59;
```

Comment: Trying to learn hybris. What process did you go through to find the answer?

Comment: I found an example from their e-commerce training sample data.